# how can find extension of file

Tags: c#

```
string[] sAllowedExt = new string[] { 
  ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png",".pdf", ".docx", ".doc" };

(!sAllowedExt.Contains(file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.IndexOf('.')).ToLower()))
```

is not working . Please suggest something else.

Comment: `Path.GetExtension(path)`

Answer (score 5):

i would use `Path.GetExtension` to determine if the extension of your file is valid.

```
string[] sAllowedExt = new string[] { 
   ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".pdf", ".docx", ".doc" };

string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

bool Result = sAllowedExt
  .Any(x => x.Equals(Extension, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```